# как отправить скриншот turtle в telebot

Tags: python, telebot, turtle

Хочу сделать так чтобы просто скриншот turtle отправлялся пользователю, но все время выдается ошибка

> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED

мне кажется что ошибка в формате файл, но как бы не было, в чем реальная ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста

```py
import turtle
import telebot

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.fd(40)
screen = t.screen
screen.getcanvas().postscript(file="file.jpg")

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<ТОКЕН>')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def func(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hello")
    photo = open("file.jpg", "rb")
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Хоть вы поставили файлу расширение `.jpg` `screen.getcanvas().postscript(file="file.jpg")`,но он от этого своё нутро не изменил. Поэтому и вылетает ошибка.

Полное описание метода `.postscript` есть [здесь](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TkCmd/canvas.html#M55).
Для того, чтоб преобразовать этот формат в более распространенные, можно

1. Установить библиотеку `Pillow`.
2. Установить `Ghostscript` — набор программного обеспечения, для работы с PostScript и документами PDF. [Можно отсюда](https://ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html).
3. Перезагрузить компьютер.

После этого запустить черепашку.

```
import turtle
from PIL import Image
# Что-нибудь рисуем на холсте, взято с SO.
x = 121
y = 1
scale = 300
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.color("black")
turtle.speed(100)
turtle.pendown()
size = 0
for i in range(scale):
    size += y
    turtle.left(x)
    turtle.forward(size)
# Сохраняем нарисованное в postscript файл.
canvas = window.getcanvas()
filename = 'out.ps'
canvas.postscript(file=filename)
# Преобразуем картинку в другой формат.
psimage = Image.open(filename)
psimage.save("bar.png")
```

В результате получаете файл в уже знакомой форме и отправляете.
Вариант с преобразованием в PDF и c другими библиотеками описан [здесь](https://pythonru.com/uroki/canvas-3-tkinter-20).

Comment: сделал также, но теперь выдает ошибку
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

Comment: Pillow не видит Ghostscript. Какая у вас система? У меня на windows 10 с pycharm автоматически подтянулся после перезагрузки. Попробуйте эти решения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587376/oserror-unable-to-locate-ghostscript-on-paths.

Comment: у меня вин 11, но тот вопрос который вы поместили, там вин7

Comment: у меня вроде получилось ghostsscript в PTH но теперь получается другая ошибка `telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content`